# android WindowManager.LayoutParams y not working

Tags: java, android, popupwindow, layoutparams

I want the background below popupwindow getting dim.But the background red rectangle marked got dim too.This is not the result I wanted.

Here's my code of setting background:

```
public void setBackgroundAlpha(float bgAlpha) {
    Window window = mContext.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = window.getAttributes();
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    layoutParams.y = mView.getBottom();//mView is the button
    layoutParams.alpha = bgAlpha; //0.0-1.0
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

`layoutParams.y` doesn't work.  Thanks for answering.
[image: the result]